# JQuery code is not defined. Function not being triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I am getting the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: toggleOptionsVisibility is not defined
> at HTMLSelectElement.onchange

My HTML:

```
    <div>
    <label asp-for="Type"></label>
    <select id="field-type" asp-for="Type" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<HourglassCopyEditor.Models.FieldType>()" onchange="javascript:toggleOptionsVisibility();"></select>
</div>

<div id="options-section" style="display: none;">
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <div id="options-container">
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Options.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="option-item">
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Options[i].Id" />
                <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.Options[i].FormFieldId" />
                <label asp-for="@Model.Options[i].Value">Option @(i + 1)</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.Options[i].Value" />
                <button type="button" class="remove-option" data-option-id="@Model.Options[i].Id">Remove</button>
            </div>
        }
        <button type="button" id="add-option">Add Option</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript/Jquery:

```
function toggleOptionsVisibility() {
    var selectedType = $('#field-type option:selected").text();
    if (selectedType == 2 || selectedType == 2 || selectedType == 3) {
        alert("show");
        $('#options-section').show();
    } else {
        alert("hide");
        $('#options-section').hide();
    }
}
```

I don't understand why my function isn't being calkled. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is toggleOptionsVisibility  in an external file or where have you defined it on your page

Comment: its in @section Scripts{}, which is rendered at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have an error in you script. Try replace

```js
var selectedType = $('#field-type option:selected").text();
```

by

```js
var selectedType = $('#field-type option:selected').text();
```

And to define the [`onchange`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event handler you can use the following syntax:

```js
onchange="toggleOptionsVisibility();"
```